# Autofill Formula in Row wise using VBA

Tags: excel

Hai i have an excel sheet, in that i need to calculate some values in row wise  first i set the values in the starting cell(A1) from that i wants to fill the formula in next 10 cell continously in row wise(A1,B1,...). i already use the code to fill the formula in column wise the code is below 
Range("Q5" & Range("Q65000").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown.
If you have any idea about the rowise Auto fill the formula then please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code that works for the column case, works even for the row case if you use Range.FillRight instead of Range.FillDown

```
Range("a1:z1").FillRight
```

Comment: You Mean ' Range("Q5"" & Range("T5").End(xlUp).Row).FillRight ' yes i am already try this But it does not work. currently i had formula in Q5 cell I wants to autofill this to cell T5

Comment: Range("a1:t1").FillRight

i've tested this on a Excel2003 Workbook and it runs smoothly.